# How to get current selected id from router in next 14

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am attempting to retrieve the currently selected id `(#about, #home, #blog)` or the complete path `(http://localhost:3000/#about, http://localhost:3000/#home)` from the router. I am using Next.js version 14.0.3

This is what I tried:
My current url is http://localhost:3000/#about

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useParams, usePathname} from "next/navigation";

function NavBar() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("#about");
 
  const params = useParams();
  console.log(params); //output: {}

  const path = usePathname();
  console.log(path); // output: /

  return <SomeComponent/>
}
```

tying to apply style to the active navigation item based on the currently selected id

Answer (score 0):

Import `useRouter` from `next/router` and fetch url of the current page like below :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function NavBar() {

  const router = useRouter(); // Access the router object using the useRouter hook
  const currentRoute = router.asPath;
  console.log(currentRoute);
  return <SomeComponent/>
}
```

Comment: I am using app directory. ```import { useRouter } from 'next/router';``` is not work           https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted